# PHP bind parm always showing error

Tags: php, pdo

this is code not working. ERROR:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$age' (T_VARIABLE) in... directory.

```
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $age = trim($_POST['age']);
        $insert= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (age, name, created) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
        $insert->bind_param('is' $age, $name);

        if($insert->execute()){

        echo 'record added';
        die();
        }
```

Comment: simple syntax error here: `$insert->bind_param('is' $age, $name);`, add `,` after `'id'`...

Comment: Try concatenating ` $insert->bind_param('is '. $age, $name);`

Comment: what does var_dump(gettype($_POST['age'])); return? note that trim function can only take strings as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `,` after Type specification chars( `is`) :

```
 $insert->bind_param('is' $age, $name);
```

should be :

```
  $insert->bind_param('is',$age, $name);
```

All parameters should be separated by `,`

Comment: I think that `'is'` is not a parameter, I think he is trying to concatenate `is` with `$age`.

Comment: @Codrutz Codrutz : `'is'` is Type specification chars. here i for integer and s for string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not following PDO rules to prepare and execute any query.

Refer following Url,

[PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing mysqli code with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $age = trim($_POST['age']);
        $insert= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (age, name, created) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
        $insert->->bindParam(1, $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insert->->bindParam(2, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);//Change 12 to suit
        if($insert->execute()){
```